# How to pass connection parameters between modules in Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I create two reports in one sheet using an Excel macro. The reports connect to Oracle DB to pull the data. The connect string that pulls the data works.

I am trying to move the connection string to a function and pass it to the respective report based on user input.

High level flow:

1. User clicks on a menu button. In the background it tries to connect to DB.
2. If the connection is successful it opens a form with button A and button B (which report the user wants to run).
3. Suppose User clicks Button A the report should be executed and displayed.

The issue is in step 2. I am not able to pass the connection parameters to Button A function.

Code for connecting to DB.

```vb
Dim dbConnect As ADODB.Connection
Dim GetData As ADODB.Recordset

'Declare a set of variables to hold the username and password for the database
Dim strUserName As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strDatabase As String
Set GetData = New ADODB.Recordset
'***

On Error Resume Next

Set dbConnect = New ADODB.Connection

dbConnect.Open ( _
  "User ID=" & strUserName & "; Password=" & strPassword & "; Data Source=" & strDatabase & "; Provider=msdaora")
 
'If the username or password is incorrect throw an error message
If (dbConnect.State <> 1) Or (Err <> 0) Then
    intResult = MsgBox("Could not connect to the database.  Check your user name and password." & vbCrLf & Error(Err), 16, " ")
Else
    '.ConnectionString = dbConnect
    ReportGenerator.Show ' this opens up another form where 
                         '  user can input the dates.
                         'This is turn calls the actual code...
End If

End Sub
```

In the Report generator form passing the date parameters to the function

```vb
Private Sub Login_Click()
    Call ReportGenerator(FromDate.Value, ToDate.Value)
End Sub
```

I need to pass the connection parameters to `CallReportGenerator` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple was you can do this:

**Option 1: Use a global variable**

If you declare a variable as `Global` on the top of a module, i.e. before any subs/functions, you can access them from any other module:

Example - Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Global gStrConnection As String 'g for Global scope

Sub Connect()
    gStrConnection = "User ID=" & strUserName & "; Password=" & strPassword & "; Data Source=" & strDatabase & "; Provider=msdaora")    
   dbConnect.Open gStrConnection
   ...
End Sub
```

Form:

```
Private Sub CreateReport()
    dbConnect.Open gStrConnection
    ...
End Sub
```

**Option 2: Pass the variable to a local form variable**

Declare a module wide variable in the Form's module (i.e. where you place the other code of the form). Then provide a small setter sub that assigns the value.

Example - Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Connect()
    Dim strConnection as String
    strConnection = "User ID=" & strUserName & "; Password=" & strPassword & "; Data Source=" & strDatabase & "; Provider=msdaora")    
   dbConnect.Open strConnection
   ...
    ReportGenerator.StoreConnectionString strConnection
    ReportGenerator.Show
    ...
End Sub
```

Form:

```
Private mStrConnection as String 'm for module-wide scope

Public Sub StoreConnectionString(strConnection as String)
    mStrConnection = strconnection
End Sub

Private Sub CreateReport()
    dbConnect.Open mStrConnection
    ...
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: used Option 1 and worked like a charm.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the connection and the recordset at the top of the standard module, outside of any procedures and set their accessors to public.

Remember to clean up resources after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach came to me as I was working through Peter Albert's Option 1. I needed to have one place to store a connection string that could be modified between development, test, and production environments for connecting to an Azure SQL Database. The approach I took declares the string as Global (gconn) and also defines the string in that module (connectDB, not visible in example) and then calls that module's Connect Sub procedure to get the global string variable. This lets me simply define the connection string in a separate module and do all opening and closing of connections in the Sub Procedures where the sql is being executed. I didn't want to execute any opening and closing Sub Procedures outside of the current module.

```vba
Option Explicit

Sub testconnection()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Call Connect
cn.Open gconn
cn.Close
```

Note that all I'm doing in the connectDB module is declaring the Global string.

```vba
Option Explicit

Global gconn As String

Sub Connect()
gconn = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;" & _
     "Data Source=AzureSQLDatabaseAddress;" & _
     "Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;" & _
     "User ID=SomeUser;" & _
     "Password=SomePassword;" & _
     "Use Encryption for Data=False;" & _
     "DataTypeCompatibility=80"

End Sub
```

This is my first answer in Stack Overflow, go easy on me :). I figured after writing SQL and VBA for almost 2 decades I should contribute a little back here.